# Abnormal behavior while predicting with training data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, predictive-modeling, statistics, supervised-learning

I am trying to predict the appearance count of a particular item using Neural Network.My data has severe class imbalance i.e 90% of data contains zero as output, remaining values ranges from 1 to 5. I am training a neural network with item features and week number of year.Whenever I run the neural network and predict for the **training data the sum of all predicted counts are equal to the sum of observed counts but the individual counts are not even getting close.I tried with both RMSE and MAE as error metrics**.I am not sure about this is correct,
 any help would be great